# 999 is close enough to 1,000 for an economist

Tags: discussion

**We reached this**

[image]

**and the numbers say this**

[image]

Note on the (currently) last remaining "Needs Work" flag: The *median* of "Visits per Day" has increased by $22 \%$ in $17$ days.

Comment: Is this intended to be a question or just a statement of facts?

Comment: @StanShunpike Well, a statement of facts (figures) always brings up the issue of interpreting and assessing them -that's the underlying question. "Opinion-based" answers are not encouraged in the main site -but in the meta-site they reign.

Comment: I would add that the requirement that questions be "actual questions" is much looser on the meta. Based on other SE, meta posts can for instance be used to create useful big threads (such as for  congratulations e.g. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/congratulations-the-big-thread) or for other kinds of useful communications to the community which do not necessarily require answers.

Comment: Visits per day has again increased by roughly 20% over the past 6 days.

Comment: @FooBar Ok. It starts to look like the asset prices bubble.

Answer (score 1):

According to other figures in your question, the relevant time-span here is the $day$.

Given that currently, there are $8.1$ question per day, $1000-999=1$ and $1/8.1 \approx 0.1234567 << 1$ (funny, isn't it?), we can say that yes, $999$ is close enough to $1000$ (for an economist).

Comment: Have you noticed that the digits progress along the naturals (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)? How more symbolic can one get? (That was 177.77 minutes, by the way).

Comment: That's what motivated the "funny, isn't it?", and giving that many digits :P